# Google Analytics E-Commerce with Measurement Protocol - (not set) Landing Page

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a problem with Landing Page that has value (not set) after pushing the transaction to Google E-Commerce using the Measurement Protocol. I'm pushing batch request from windows service wrote in C# code resulting in such request:

```
POST http://www.google-analytics.com/batch HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Host: www.google-analytics.com
Content-Length: 390
Expect: 100-continue

v=1&t=transaction&tid=UA-00000000-0&cid=1812230000.1454578095&ti=1&ta=someshop&tr=50.00&cu=GBP&dh=someshop.co.uk&dp=/buy&dt=BuyItem&dl=http://localhost:55777/Results/
v=1&t=item&tid=UA-00000000-0&cid=1812230000.1454578095&ti=1&ic=00001&in=SoldItem&ip=50.00&iq=1&iv=ItemCategory&cu=GBP&dl=http://localhost:55777/Results/
```

I can see the transaction under analytics with all mandatory data but when I go to Behaviour -> Site Content -> Landing Pages report I can see that my transaction is logged under (not set) landing page.

The transaction data as I mentioned is posted by the windows service with delay because the transaction revenue is fetched from external provider in hour or two after actual transaction made by the user. To connect transaction with the user (not logged) I'm using the clientId from GA cookie. I've tried to pass the location but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to log/connect landing page along with transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the original landing page then probably not - sessions restart after 30 minutes inactivity (so if there is a delay before the server call the session might be expired) or when campaign information changes, as it would if you do do a serverside call.

If your users are logged in during transactions you might try the [userid feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) with session unification.

Given the number of things that would have to match to continue an existing session (traffic source, medium and campaign info, timeframe of session, clientid, and I think user agent and ip) I would venture that there is currently no reliable way to connect serverside calls and web sessions.

Disclaimer: I have little to back up my opinion other than my own attempts to do this. Documentation sure makes it sound like this should be possible.

You would probably be able to find the original landing page via the user explorer report (look at the conversion, then look at the landing page for the previous session), but you can't access this programmatically.

Or try an advanced segment of the sequence type - look at users who have visited the confirmation page, and have in later interaction a transaction (via the server call). This *might* give you clue which landig page lead to a transaction.